# Как получить список WiFi сетей в терминале?

Tags: wifi, linux

Всем Hi! Собственно вопрос, как можно получить список достипных Wifi сетей вокруг? Мой вариант:

> iwlist wlan0 scan

Но есть ли что-то более точное? И чтоб стандартно из коробки. Пишу скрипт для визуализации работы wifi. Когда включался/выключался. Так что мне с это команды только bssid сети надо и все. А то iwlisit столько инфы выкладывает, аж жуть((( Используется Linux Mint 14

**P.s. Airodump-ng мне не нужен!**

Answer (score 1):

iwlist scan | grep ESSID - не оно?

Answer (score 0):

я думаю нет - не это ТС нужно.
Данная команда выдает имя уже подключенной сети. А он желает просканировать все доступные

Comment: man iwlist PARAMETERS       scan[ning]              Give  the  list  of Access Points and Ad-Hoc cells in range, and optionally a whole bunch of information about them              (ESSID, Quality, Frequency, Mode...)

Comment: Ну у меня и выдает текущую точку (сеть) к которой подключен.  Перечень других вай-фай сетей в вокруг - не дает.

Comment: А вы полностью пункт мана про параметр "scan[ning]" прочитали? Там в серединке самое интересное: "Triggering  scanning  is  a privileged operation (root only) and normal users can only read left-over scan results.  By  default, the way scanning is done (the scope of the scan) is dependant on the card and card settings."